# Why does my for loop skip my last values in my array?

Tags: c++, arrays

My program is supposed to count how many unique values there are in an array.  So far I have sorted the array in ascending order (just to play with the different algorithms), and am dealing with trying to count how many values each unique value has (4,4,4,4,2,3,2 where 2 is 2 and 3 is 1).

I have an example array I have been testing this with, and it consists of numbers 1-10, but my for loops will only go up to counting 8.  It is probably something obvious, but right now I am just stuck trying to find the bug.

The snippet of my code that is affected:

Index = the size of the array

```
for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
{
    uniqueness = true;

    for (int l = 0; l < index; l++)
    {

        if (numbers[i] == temporary[l])
        {
            uniqueness = false;
        }
    }

    if (uniqueness)
    {
        temporary[i] = numbers[i];

        number_amount = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < index; j++)
        {
            if (numbers[j] == temporary[i])
            {
                number_amount++;
            }
        }

        Output(temporary[i], number_amount);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are missing code for the most interesting part - "Index = the size of the array".

Comment: Your loop variable goes up to, but not including, `index`. While we have no way of knowing what `index` actually is, the name is a bit suspect. Why isn't it called `length`?

Comment: Use of `if (uniqueness)` seems wrong. I think it should be the opposite, `if (!uniqueness)`.

Comment: using c++ algorithms: 
const int n = 6;

int numbers[n] = {1, 10, 20, 20, 10, 1};

sort(numbers, numbers + n);

int unique_numbers[n];

auto itr = unique_copy(numbers, numbers + n, unique_numbers);

int unique_count = distance(unique_numbers, itr);

cout << unique_count;

Comment: numbers[i] == temporary[l] ; What's inside temporary[] array and numbers[] array ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wmjtxa5d/1/             i have completed with javascript. if u want convert it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/* Finding unique number from an array After sorting the Array*/

```
int arr = [ 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9];
int unique[arr.length];
int arrCount = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < arr.length;) {
    bool isUnique = true;
    int currentIndex = i + 1;

    for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
        if (arr[i] == arr[j]) {
            isUnique = false;
        } else {
            currentIndex = j;
            break;
        }
    }

    i = currentIndex;

    if (isUnique) {  
        unique[arrCount]=arr[i - 1];
        arrCount++;
    }

}

enter code here
```

Comment: I completed with javascript http://jsfiddle.net/wmjtxa5d/1/  if any pbm with above c++ solution, pls refer the fiddle code

Answer (score -1):

For all your for loops, it should be "<= index" rather than "< index", considering you have index set right. that's because it loops only until it reaches a value lower than index (< index), not the index itself (<= index).

Comment: The array index starts at 0, so if the size of array is 5, the last index would be 4 not 5. There is a difference between the size and indices of an array.

Comment: char a[4]={a,b,c,d} ; this means a[0]=a; a[1]=b;a[2]=c;a[3]=d; array index starts from 0 to (size-1).